# How to fix Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them using bindings.xjb

Tags: jaxb

Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationException

My bindings file is as follows:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">
    <xjc:simple />
</jaxb:globalBindings>

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/FISCommonRqstHdr_v2_1/FISCommonRqstHdr_v2_1.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.request" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/FISCommonRspHdr_v2_1/FISCommonRspHdr_v2_1.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.response" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/XPBusinessObjects/Common_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">

    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.common_v2_0" />

    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>    

<jaxb:bindings
schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/XPBusinessObjects/ContactPoint_v2_0.xsd"
if-exists="true">
<jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.contactpoint_v2_0" />
</jaxb:schemaBindings>    
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/XPBusinessObjects/InvolvedParty_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>    

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/XPBusinessObjects/OrganizationalUnit_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.organizationalunit_v2_0" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/XPBusinessObjects/ResourceItem_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.resourceitem_v2_0" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>  
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/XPBusinessObjects/XPOrganizationalUnit_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.dom.xporganizationalunit_v2_0" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings> 

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/messages/XPRetrieveEmployeeListRqst_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package
            name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.svc.xporgunitiplistprofile_v2_0.xpretrieveemployeelist_v2_0.request" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../../src/main/resources/WSDLs/messages/XPRetrieveEmployeeListRsp_v2_0.xsd"
    if-exists="true">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package
            name="com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.svc.xporgunitiplistprofile_v2_0.xpretrieveemployeelist_v2_0.response" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Need help with how to override the nameType annotation using bindings.xjb

Two classes have the same XML type name "{urn:Fis:Common}Value". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace

```
this problem is related to the following location:                                                     

    at com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.common_v2_0.Value                                                

    at protected com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.common_v2_0.Value com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedpa

    at com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.IpCommonDemographic                           

    at public com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.IpCommonDemographic com.fis.ec.base.svc

    at com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.ObjectFactory                                 

this problem is related to the following location:                                                     

    at com.fis.ec.svc.xp.bom.common_v2_0.Value                                                     

    at protected com.fis.ec.svc.xp.bom.common_v2_0.Value fis.communication.CommunicationPreference.

    at fis.communication.CommunicationPreference                                                   

    at protected java.util.List com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.IpPreference.commPrev

    at com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.IpPreference                                  

    at protected com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.IpPreference com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.

    at com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.InvolvedParty                                 

    at public com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.InvolvedParty com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bo

    at com.fis.ec.base.svc.xp.bom.involvedparty_v2_0.ObjectFactory                                 



at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.ja

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)                

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)                        

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)                        

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)     

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)                           

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                         

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)                       

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)               

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)                                                    

at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)                                    

at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:392)                                           

at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618)                                        

at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345)                        

at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:343)                        

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)                                          

at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:343)                

at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:244)   

at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:484)           

at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:339)
```

Comment: The problem is finally fixed. The issue was 2 different jars containing the Value object with same xmlType are present in the classpath, I have removed one of the jars using exclusions in my war project pom file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425020/two-classes-have-the-same-xml-type-name-objectfactory-org-glassfish-jaxb-run - Can you please check this one?